# Выход за границы поля TextField

Tags: java, javafx

Как можно сделать перенос текста на следующую строку при вводе?
(Когда текст доходит к границе поля,он как бы начинает двигать его,скрывая предыдущий текст)

Comment: а что пробовали вы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как правило TextField (для ввода однострочного текста), TextArea (для ввода многострочного текста), я не знаю для насколько принципиально Вам необходим TextField, поэтому просто порекомендую TextArea, к примеру так:

```
void setPrefColumnCount(int columns)    // устанавливает кол-во столбцов
void setPrefRowCount(int rows)          // устанавливает кол-во строк
```

далее пример

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;

public class Main extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        Label lbl = new Label();
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setPrefColumnCount(15);
        textArea.setPrefRowCount(5);
        Button btn = new Button("Click");
        btn.setOnAction(event -> lbl.setText("Input: " + textArea.getText()));
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL, 10, 10, textArea, btn, lbl);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("TextArea in JavaFX");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```